# How to use windows sandbox on ryzen 5 processor

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, amd-processor, windows-sandbox

So, my goal is to use windows sandbox on my machine.
How can I make this work?

In my BIOS, SVM is enabled.

But when trying to install/activate windows sandbox via "Turn Windows features on or off" it just gives the error tooltip: "Windows Sandbox cannot be installed: Virtualization support is disabled in the firmware."

amdvhyperv.exe gives:
"This system is compatible with Hyper-V'".
This AMD64 system supports AMD Virtualization"* (AMD-V'") Technology with Rapid Virtualization Indexing."

Taskmanager > Performance > CPU gives: "Virtualization: Disabled"

In the following some information from "system information":

- My OS:

  - OS Name   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
  - Version   10.0.19044 Build 19044
  - List item
- My processor

  - Processor AMD Ryzen 5 3600X 6-Core Processor, 3793 Mhz, 6 Core(s), 12 Logical Processor(s)
- My Mainboard

  - BIOS Version/Date American Megatrends Inc. F11, 191206
  - SMBIOS Version    3.2
  - Embedded Controller Version   255.255
  - BIOS Mode UEFI
  - BaseBoard Manufacturer    Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
  - BaseBoard Product X570 UD
  - BaseBoard Version x.x
- Regarding Virtualization it says:

  - Hyper-V - VM Monitor Mode Extensions  Yes
  - Hyper-V - Second Level Address Translation Extensions Yes
  - Hyper-V - Virtualization Enabled in Firmware  No
  - Hyper-V - Data Execution Protection   Yes

Answer (score 0):

I happened to solve my issue.

The solution that worked for my machine:

1. Activate SVM in the BIOS.
2. In "Turn Windows features on or off" activate
   a. Hyper-V
   b. Windows Hypervisor Platform
3. Restart
4. In "Turn Windows features on or off" activate
   a. Windows Sandbox
5. Restart

In step 2 I assume only one of the features is strictly necessary to make windows sandbox activable, but don't know which.